# Custom Upload Page still works for Document Library of SharePoint 2016?

Tags: 2010, powershell, 2016, file-upload, custom

I have a requirement where I need to create one custom upload page for one document library, so I built the code in a webpart control. 
In that form I have set custom upload control and some meta data controls. 
That webpart was placed inside a Site page and I was setting site page path to new custom upload page by following PowerShell:

```
 $web = Get-SPWeb <<SPSIteURL>>
 $web.CustomuploadPage = "/SitePages/NewUpload.aspx"
 $web.Update()
```

Now this code was working on SharePoint 2010 environment, while the same I try to replicate on SharePoint 2016 environment, it doesn't work at all. Like it does run PowerShell snippet successfully but doesn't change anything at the Upload click on the document library.

So does any one have idea if this is still supportive for SharePoint 2016 environment?

If there is no support available, any other possible way out to set custom upload page for document library in SharePoint 2016?

Any help would be much appreciated!